# ¿Por qué cuando alguien es malo o incompetente en una actividad decimos que "es un/a manta"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos

En español "ser alguien una manta, o un manta" es una locución adverbial que significa "Ser un holgazán o un inútil" [de acuerdo al DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OGLG0tA).

Este significado coloquial no se infiere fácil o directamente de las acepciones de "manta".

¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "ser un manta" para referirse a alguien que es malo o incompetente en una actividad?

Comment: Esta acepción de _manta_ es muy reciente, aparece por primera vez en el _Academia Manual_ de 1984 como neologismo. Es complicado rastrear el origen de estas acepciones modernas, así que solo puedo dar un par de opiniones locas de las mías. Una es que derive de la acepción relativa a la _manta de palos_, y otra que se aplique a las personas holgazanas a las que les gusta estar debajo de una manta.

Comment: Diego, ¿a quién doy la recompensa? :)

Comment: @fedorqui A mi la que más me gusta de momento es la de Ramón,pero básicamente las tres son casi iguales, igual de verosímiles, igual de difíciles de verificar...

Answer (score 1):

Este blog recoge dos posibilidades:

> #### Origen
>
> Se asocia sin dificultad un vago con mantas por su querencia a estar entre ellas. Probablemente fuera ‘vago’ el primer significado que tomara esta expresión. El origen de manta con el sentido de inútil o poco hábil no está claro. Según A. Buitrago (Diccionario de dichos y frases hechas) es posible que
>
> > «las connotaciones negativas de la locución se identifiquen con la baja calidad del tejido de las mantas de antaño y con la suciedad y parásitos que en ellas se acumulaban».
>
> Por otra parte, Buitrago ve una posible conexión con el lienzo en el que se escribían los nombres de los judíos que se convertían y que se colgaba en algunas iglesias del norte de España, especialmente en Navarra, entre los siglos XVI y XVII, y se pregunta lo siguiente:
>
> > «¿No se llamaría también manta, a causa de una sencilla y común metonimia, como el trompeta o el maleta, al que apareciera en aquella lista? Desde luego, sería alguien con no muy buena fama entre sus vecinos».
>
> Sin embargo, si consultamos el Mapa de diccionarios académicos, vemos que aún no se recogía en el Diccionario de 1925.
>
> - https://www.blasita.com/ser-un-manta-o-un-maleta/

Además dice esto el [*Inventario general de insultos*](http://www.robertexto.com/archivo17/insultos_p.htm) en la sección de "Pelafustán":

> Holgazán; persona indolente y despreciable que merodea por el pueblo en busca más de beneficio que de oficio; pobre de solemnidad sin voluntad ni fuerza para salir de su miseria. Como los términos "pelagallos y pelagatos", es palabra compuesta, en este caso del verbo "pelar", y del substantivo fustán = tela gruesa de algodón con pelo por una de sus caras. **El pelafustán pasa tanto tiempo tumbado con la manta encima que llega a pelarla. Las expresiones: "andar con la manta", "no quitarse la manta", "ser un manta", estan en relación con lo que decimos, cayendo de lleno en el ámbito de la holgazanería.**

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Charlie, es complicado rastrear el origen de este tipo de expresiones. Pero indagando un poco, he podido encontrar en algunas webs o libros algunas propuestas repetidas con variaciones. A la espera de que alguien haya dado con la explicación definitiva, os muestro aquí algunas de esas hipótesis.

[En un blog](https://www.blasita.com/ser-un-manta-o-un-maleta/) se refieren al *[Diccionario de dichos y frases hechas](https://books.google.es/books/about/Diccionario_de_dichos_y_frases_hechas.html?id=UV23VTQe4PQC&redir_esc=y)* de Buitrago, donde este refiere que

> las connotaciones negativas de la locución se identifiquen con la baja calidad del tejido de las mantas de antaño y con la suciedad y parásitos que en ellas se acumulaban

Y cito del blog:

> También ve una posible conexión con el lienzo en el que se escribían los nombres de los judíos que se convertían y que se colgaba en algunas iglesias del norte de España, especialmente en Navarra, entre los siglos XVI y XVII.

Es una explicación que puede convencer, y que cito la primera por provenir de un trabajo publicado y contrastado.

Otra explicación que aparece a menudo, sobre todo en webs relativas a Salamanca, como [esta](https://mipuntodepartida.travelclub.es/5-curiosidades-de-alcala-de-henares-que-no-conocias/) o [esta](http://viajandocadadia.blogspot.com/2019/02/alcala-de-henares-ciudad-patrimonio-de.html), relacionan la expresión con la manta de los estudiantes, ya sea la manta de los estudiantes pobres, o la manta de los suspendidos:

> Los estudiantes que suspendían, se les podía identificar fácilmente siglos atrás porque portaban unas orejas de burro y una manta, siendo manteados a la puerta de la Universidad, de ahí surgió la expresión “ser un manta”.

Por último, en el [Inventario de los insultos](https://issuu.com/vjcasanova/docs/libro_de_los_insultos), de Pancracio Celdrán, y que se puede consultar on-line, he encontrado otra explicación que relaciona manta también con pobreza:

> Persona torpe y holgazana, sin oficio ni domicilio conocidos, que anda de un sitio a otro en busca de no se sabe qué. Del hecho de llevar estos individuos consigo la manta con que arroparse derivó el calificativo.

En definitiva, no parece haber origen concreto y contrastado, y sí mucha especulación. Sin embargo, mientras no llegue esa explicación clara, me ha parecido interesante compartir estas otras.

Comment: Gran contribución. Gracias. Quizá la marque como respuesta aceptada (al menos hasta que alguien proponga otra mejor), ya que es posible que no demos nunca con el origen exacto.

Answer (score 1):

Me atrevo a dar una explicación alternativa, que no he podido contrastar pero que me parece más plausible por su sencillez.

La expresión *ser un manta* o también *ser una manta*, [según el diccionario](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OGLG0tA#69DfjSJ), se usa para describir a un holgazán o a un inútil. La expresión es relativamente reciente, aparece recogida en el libro "[Vivir en Madrid](https://books.google.es/books?id=cG4JAQAAIAAJ&q=%22un%20manta%22&dq=%22un%20manta%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir__qGpePhAhVOyxoKHeL_AKo4ChDoAQgxMAI)", de 1967, y también en el "[Archivo de filología aragonesa](https://books.google.es/books?id=nmk2AAAAIAAJ&q=%22un%20manta%22&dq=%22un%20manta%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir__qGpePhAhVOyxoKHeL_AKo4ChDoAQhKMAg)", de 1958:

> PEREZA: *manta* com. 'persona perezosa', por ejemplo: *Pepe 's un manta n' ha 'rrancau los garbazos*, etc.

Más allá no encuentro ejemplos exactos, pero sí casos de otra expresión muy similar: *manta mojada*. El primero lo veo en la hemeroteca de la BNE:

> [...] y si otro es su sentir bajará la cabeza y le vendrá muy ancho, que no soy
>   yo ninguna manta mojada, y cuando yo digo quiero y mando...
>
> **El Álbum de las familias (Barcelona).** 9/9/1860, página 3.

Más:

> Mi primo era un infeliz... un melancólico... una manta mojada...
>
> **Revista ilustrada.** 16/2/1881, página 5.

Esta expresión también es de uso en Ecuador, según el DLE y [el DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=manta), donde se define como "*referido a persona*, falta de coraje y determinación". Y de hecho en 1869 se recoge en el *Domínguez Suplemento* como:

> *Ser una manta mojada;* fr. fam. Ser inútil, no servir para nada.

Y anteriormente en el *Salvá* de 1846:

> SER UNA MANTA MOJADA. fr. fam. Ser inútil, no servir para nada.

Y también aparece la expresión recogida en un [diccionario español-francés de 1805](https://books.google.es/books?id=QMtFAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA51&dq=%22manta%20mojada%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSie-2sOPhAhUFxhoKHUVDAwgQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22manta%20mojada%22&f=false). Por lo visto en francés existe además la expresión "[cubrirse con una manta mojada](https://books.google.es/books?id=8qKU9e0ilVcC&pg=PA177&dq=%22manta%20mojada%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig5LDqruPhAhXtxoUKHV4wCOMQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=%22manta%20mojada%22&f=false)" con el significado de "agravar una falta con una mala excusa".

Luego la expresión *ser una manta mojada* ya tenía en el siglo XIX el mismo significado que el actual *ser un manta*. No sería descabellado que la expresión acabara acortándose eliminando lo de *mojada*, y se quedara en *ser una manta*, y de ahí se masculinizara el sustantivo cuando se aplicaba como adjetivo a personas del mismo sexo masculino (entiendo que se usa *ser una manta* cuando se aplica a mujeres).

Por tanto, el origen se trasladaría al origen de "manta mojada", el cual entiendo que proviene del uso de *manta* como algo con lo que te cubres para entrar en calor, cosa que es inútil si la manta está mojada.

El problema que le veo a esta teoría es el salto temporal tan grande que hay desde los últimos usos en España de *ser una manta mojada*, hacia el último cuarto del siglo XIX, y los primeros usos de *ser un manta*, de mediados del siglo XX. En Ecuador la expresión *manta mojada* parece ser del primer tercio del siglo XX.

Comment: Interesante - por contraste, la traducción literal de *manta mojada* en inglés (["wet blanket"](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/wet-blanket.html)) significa *aguafiestas/sosaina*.